# Spring Data - ManyToOne not persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my application, i have these three classes

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class CpamEntity {

    @Id
    private String externalId;
    
    @Field
    private String cgr;
    
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<AttachmentEntity> attachments;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "externalId")
    private Set<DataEntity> data;

}

@Entity
@Indexed
public class DataEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String internalId;
    
    @Field
    private String number;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "externalId", updatable = false)
    private FrameworkEntity frameworkEntity;
    
}
```

the below code is to insert DataEntity (X) into CpamEntity, then get all attachments CpamEntity by IdChild and insert the same DataEntity (X) in them

the problem is the first insertion doesn't happen, and the attachments CpamEntity insered

```
public void on(Event event) {
        CpamEntity cpamEntity = getCpamEntity(event.externalId);
        if (cpamEntity != null) {
            Set<DataEntity> datas = cpamEntity.getData();
            datas.add(new DataEntity(event.internalId, event.number));
            cpamEntity.setData(datas);
            repository.save(cpamEntity); // not saved
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(cpamEntity.getAttachments())) {
                cpamEntity.getAttachments().forEach(attachment -> {
                    cpamRepositoryentity = repository.findByCgr(attachment.getIdChild());
                    if (entity != null) {
                        Set<Entity> dataEntities = entity.getData();
                        dataEntities.add(new DataEntity(event.internalId, event.number));
                        entity.setData(dataEntities);
                        cpamRepository.save(entity); // saved
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where the `@Transactional`. boundaries at the moment? And can you do print of `datas` before and after `datas.add(new DataEntity(event.internalId, event.number));`?

Comment: Is **externalId** the CpamEntity's primary key in the db?